# Google map api stopped in hauwi phone in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm using google map api v2 in android and my code is like below,it's work fine in rest of phones but stopped working in huawi phone's,

```
  <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
                android:layout_span="2" />
```

whats the wrong in my code?

```
this is my manifest file code related to the map activity :
  <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="myApiKey" />
   <activity
            android:name="com.toranjSoft.contractors.MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the lack of Google Play Services on your devices. I think the same problem happens on Amazon Fire phone. You can try to install the play services and see if it solve the problem http://forum.xda-developers.com/fire-phone/general/fire-phone-how-to-install-google-play-t2977237